# Android - Impact of changing app install location from SD card to internal storage?

Tags: android, installation, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I'm working on an in-market Android app that has long allowed installation on either internal or external storage.  However, the app includes several widgets so we really should prevent it from being installed on external storage.  We get regular complaints about the widgets disappearing or otherwise misbehaving (known issues with SD card installations), so I think we need to eliminate the external storage option.

My questions are:

1. What happens to existing users after we switch from allowing external to requiring internal (change installLocation = "auto" -> "internalOnly" in the manifest)?  Are there any gotchas here, or will the OS simply move the app to internal storage? **EDIT:** ***From my limited testing, this appears to work smoothly assuming there is sufficient internal storage.  After I changed to "internalOnly" and updated the app, it was seamlessly moved from the SD card to internal storage without incident or user notification.***
2. What if the existing user doesn't have enough internal storage for the updated app?  Will they just get an "insufficient storage available" error, or something worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app will move to the internal store of the phone if the memory is availabe otherwise it will throw an error "insufficient storage available"

Comment: Can you confirm somehow that existing users will get exceptions?